# Swift_RfcComplianceException: Address in mailbox given [] does not comply with RFC 2822, 3.6.2

Tags: php, laravel, mail

Estoy tratando de ajustar en envío personalizado de correo electrónico con Laravel y aparece el siguiente error:

Swift_RfcComplianceException: Address in mailbox given [] does not comply with RFC 2822, 3.6.2. in file /app4/httpd/19-myapp/vendor/swiftmailer/swiftmailer/lib/classes/Swift/Mime/Headers/MailboxHeader.php on line 355

.env

```
MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=smtp.office365.com
MAIL_PORT=587
MAIL_USERNAME=desarrollo@gmail.co
MAIL_PASSWORD=******
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=tls
MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS=desarrollo@gmail.co
MAIL_FROM_NAME="recover"
MAIL_SUBJECT="Some subject"
```

App/Mail/UserSendRecover.php

```
class UserSendRecover extends Mailable
{
    use Queueable, SerializesModels;

    /**
     * Create a new message instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public $data;
    public function __construct($data)
    {
        $this->data = $data;
    }

    /**
     * Build the message.
     *
     * @return $this
     */
    public function build()
    {
       
      return $this->from(env('MAIL_FROM'), env('APP_NAME'))
                   ->view('emails.recover_password')
                    ->subject('Recuperar su contraseña')
                    ->with($this->data);
    }
}
```

controlador

```
public function postRecover(Request $request)

{
    $rules=[
           'email'=> 'required|email',
        ];
    $user = Users::where('email', $request->input('email'))->count();
    if($user == '1')
    {
        $user = Users::where('email', $request->input('email'))->first();
        $code = rand(100000, 999999);
        $data = ['firstname' => $user->firstname, 'lastname' => $user->lastname, 'code' => $code];
        $emailuser = str_replace("\xE2\x80\x8B", "", $user->email);
        Mail::to($emailuser)->send(new UserSendRecover($data));
        
    }
    else
    {
        return "email does not exist";
    }
}
```

Ya he intentado varias soluciones publicadas, como agregar `str_replace("\xE2\x80\x8B", "", $user->email)`, `config:clear` y nada me ha funcionado.

Agradezco mucho su ayuda, :)

Comment: ¿Si le haces un `dd` a `$user->email` si obtienes el valor del email?

Comment: Si señor 
  dd($user->email)
"correo@gmail.co"

Comment: Hice config:cache y ahora sale el siguiente error:

Swift_RfcComplianceException: Address in mailbox given [] does not comply with RFC 2822, 3.6.2. in file /app4/httpd/19-myapp/vendor/swiftmailer/swiftmailer/lib/classes/Swift/Mime/Headers/MailboxHeader.php on line 355

Answer (score 1):

Funcionó al configurar el App/Mail/UserSendRecover.php

De la siguiente manera

```
public function build()
    {
       
      return $this->view('emails.recover_password')
      /*return $this->from(env('MAIL_FROM'), env('APP_NAME'))
                   ->view('emails.recover_password')*/
                    ->subject('Recuperar su contraseña')
                    ->with($this->data);
    }
```